# arm-none-symbianelf-ld throwing "No Such File or Directory" error looking for file [...].GCCE.UREL.objects.via when building project

Tags: symbian, mobile-phones, flashlite, carbide

Im using Carbide C++ 2.3.0 to build a Flash Stub project with S60)5th_Edition_SDK-v1.0 Phone Release (GCCE) set as build configuration. I have installed Perl and JRE and the CSL toolchain (GCCE), and Ive manually updated the Windows PATH variable to point to GCCE/bin.

When I create my project according to - [this article](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Create_Flash_Applications_with_Carbide.c++) and click build I get only the following error message -

```
@\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\*[name]\*group\*[NAME]*\GCCE\*[name]*_0xECB9C23A.GCCE.UREL.objects.via: No such file: No such file or directory
```

The console output is -

```
arm-none-symbianelf-ld: @\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\EPOC32\BUILD\Symbian\Carbide\workspace\name\group\NAME\GCCE\name_0xECB9C23A.GCCE.UREL.objects.via: No such file: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [\S60\devices\S60_5th_Edition_SDK_v1.0\epoc32\release\gcce\urel\name_0xECB9C23A.exe] Error 1
make: *** [TARGETCUEMEMMOB] Error 2
```

My errors log panel shows that Perlv5.6.1 was not detected (i installed strawberry perl 5.10.1) should this matter?

I have checked that the EPOCROOT is set correctly and navigated in windows explorer to the file that cannot be found and I can see it there.

I cannot find any help with this on the nokia forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it matters.
The recommended perl implementation is ActivePerl 5.6.1, available from activestate.com

Comment: Thanks - I have uninstalled Strawberry perl and downloaded and installed Active Perl 5.6.1 from activestate.com. I checked PATH variables and tried to build again but get the same error message about File not Found. Perl is now being detected obviously as this has disappeared from the errors panel. Any thoughts on my other error message?

Comment: OK actually it works fine, I started fresh with a new project and it worked a treat. thanks!